# adding value to key=value iff value not present, from python

Tags: python, linux, sed

I'm trying to edit a configuration file from a python script. The config file, by default, contains `key=` on a line by itself, without a value. But the user might have edited the conf file so that it says `key=value1`. If that's the case, I don't want to edit value, but leave it alone. My call to sed looks like this:

```
from subprocess import call

call(["/bin/sed", "-i", "s/key=\\n/key=val/", confPath])
```

But this fails to match. I've tried it with `\n` instead of `\\n` and sed crashes due to 'unterminated s command'. I've tried it with `\\r`, but that also doesn't match.

Note that I cannot call `s/key=/key=val/` because I could end up with `key=valval1` in the conf file, if the file already contained `key=val1`.

Comment: To avoid any issues caused by escaping in Python, I recommend using raw strings for the arguments of sed, for example `r"s/key=\\n/key=val/"`. Also you might want to use `$` to signify the end of line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm all in favor of @Jan's solution for using python's `ConfigParser`, but if you really like using regular expressions, you can use the `$` end-of-line indicator instead of using '\n' explicitly:

```
call(["/bin/sed", "-i", "s/key=$/&val/", confPath])
```

`key=$` means "match the string 'key=' with nothing else after it in that line".

`&` means "include here everything you managed to match", which in your case is "{KEY}="

Answer (score 2):

Try to use real power of Python, this time it has nickname `ConfigParser` module, it gives you full comfort for this kind of work

https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html

Having cfg.ini:

```
[Main]
name=Jan
surname=Vlcinsky
```

You can play with it:

```
>>> import ConfigParser
>>> fname = "cfg.ini"
>>> config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser({"age": 100})
>>> config.get("Main", "name")
"Jan"
>>> config.get("Main", "age")
100
```

Default for key "age" is given at the moment of `ConfigParser.RawConfigParser`. Other ConfigParser parsers support that too.

This was reading, writing is possible too.